# How can I change column headers in SQL dynamically?

Tags: sql, relational-database, db2-luw

I have 2 tables.

```
UI_COMPONENT
UI_ID   LABEL_ID    UI_Name
01      Label1      Custom_Name
02      Label2      Random_text
03      Label3      Dummy_Label
```

What this means is the html page is going to have 3 textbox who will have labels as Custom_Name, Random_text and Dummy_Label.
Ex:

Custom_Name: ___________________

Random_text: ___________________

Dummy_Label: ___________________

And whatever we fill in these textboxes is stored in another table:

```
UI_COMPONENT_VALUES:
ID      Label1      Label2      Label3
111     John        Doe         Millers
222     David                   Gabriel
```

Admin has access to rename UI_COMPONENT labels.
I need to create a view where I can display values from UI_COMPONENT_VALUES with dynamic headers.
or at least can you help me with an SQL query which retrieves data in the below mentioned manner?

Expected Output:

```
UI_COMPONENT_VALUES_VIEW:
ID      Custom_Name     Random_text     Dummy_Label
111     John            Doe             Millers
222     David                           Gabriel
```

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for this (I think).

Comment: Unfortunately column names of a View are a part of DDL, which means that to modify it you have to execute DDL statement. The second approach already mentioned by @TimBiegeleisen is to generate script dynamically. But that means you cannot do it through view, it has to be Stored Procedure.

Comment: As mentioned stored proc is probably the best way to do what you want, but be aware that every distinct statement than is encountered by the database will be compiled and that can sometimes take longer than the statement execution.